# Is there any conferences/symposiums/workshops/schools aggregator service?

Tags: resource-request

I'm looking for a conference/etc.. for next year and I've found that this information is very much scattered about. One almost has to know beforehand the existence of a given conference/etc.. because otherwise it is almost impossible to find it.

Is there a service that aggregates this type of information?

Comment: Many professional society web pages have links to conferences of interest to their members. And I seem to get all kinds of (junk) emails announcing conferences that someone mistakenly thinks I should be interested in. Ask around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Canadian Astronomy Data Centre](https://www.cadc-ccda.hia-iha.nrc-cnrc.gc.ca/en/meetings/index.html) compile a list of international astronomy meetings.

I can't guarantee completeness but it lists two out of two of the meetings I plan to attend next year.